# how to store pdf on server using html-pdf?

Tags: angularjs, html-pdf

I am using html-pdf to create pdf. After new user subscribes for product then admin fills data and generate pdf for that user. Now i want to make it available to show/download that pdf to user when he visits profile page . Is there any way to store pdf on server with respect to product and name .Thanks in advance.